# Winning Percentages

Tags: probability, statistics

A friend and I both play in an NFL pick league.  His requires that he only pick 5 games per week.  So far there have been 76 total games this year.  His record is 18 for 25.

My league requires me to pick a winner for every game.  My record is 40 for 76.

What would be the formula for comparing our winning percentages since my league is obviously much harder?

Answer (score 0):

My strategy for answering this question is not nearly as in-depth as I would like, but it's the best I could think of.

I'm going to reduce the question to "if your friend had participated in your pick league, would he have beaten you?"

Out of $76$ games, your friend has already picked $25$, which means he has $51$ left to pick.  Out of those $51$ games, he must get $22$ correct in order to match the total of $18+22=40$ correct picks.

If your friend scored exactly the needed $22/51$, he would have actually done worse than random guessing. So, if your friend randomly guessed at all of the other $51$ games, he would still be expected to beat you, with an average of $43.5/76$ vs $40/76$.  For this reason, I think he is winning.

What I'm really interested in, though, is a more general-case solution.  This answer relied on a special-case, which is that $22/51 < 1/2$.